# Actuarial problem. Amortization Problem in a 25 year period at 5%

Tags: calculus, actuarial-science

> From The problem statment: What is the monthly payment for a $800,000
>   mortgage for the first 119 payments that is due in 10 years, has a 25
>   year amortization, at 5% interest? What is the amount of the 120th
>   payment?

**PV: 800,000** from loan
is due in 10 years,

and 25 amortization at 5% then, from here I have

**Monthly interest I/Y:**

5/12 = **0.42**

**Amount of payments N:**

25*12= **300 payments**

Then I have:

```
N      I/Y        PV        PMT     FV     
300     0.42      800K       ?       0
```

PMT= -4,699.09

Now at **payment 119** 
     I paid : -559,192.19 each payment of -4,699.09

and at 120 I will paid: -563,891 and left a **balloon payment of 236,108.71** = 800k-563,891

**Question: Is it my work correct or I'm missing something? Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

The monthly interest is not 1/12 of the annual interest but 1 less than the 12-th root of 1 more, i.e.,

$$(1+0.05)^{1/12}-1=0.004074...$$

or slightly less than 0.41 percent.

Comment: If I change, and use 0.4074. My procedure  was correct?

Comment: Why is it 1 less than the 12th root of one more? Why does the -1 come into play?

Comment: In compound interest, it is the total (principal, represented as 1 or 100 percent, plus interest) that is raised to the power of the number of periods (in this case 12). The 1 between the brackets represents adding the principal to the interest. The minus 1 outside the brackets is the inverse operation because I was trying to obtain the effective interest.